# Unterminated address regex when using sed for XML comments

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to run the following command with a shell script:

```
sed -i -e \'s\/<!-- XML Comment 1 -->\/<!--XML Comment 2 -->\/g; s\/<!-- XML Comment 3 -->\/<!--XML Comment 4 -->\/g\'
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated address regex
```

When I try escaping from the '<' or '!', the message just changes from "char 9" to "char 10". When I escape both, the error is at char 11. Is there some other character I need to escape?

Comment: you have to escape both of those

Comment: Why are you escaping all the apostrophes and slashes?!

Comment: Escaping both of them just changes the error to "char 11"

Comment: @user2824889 Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Biffen I'm using Bash

Comment: @user2824889 Strange. I get `!--: No such file or directory` when I try it, partly because of the escaped apostrophes. Would you mind explaining those?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to escape `'` and `/`.

```
sed -i -e 's/<!-- XML Comment 1 -->/<!--XML Comment 2 -->/g; s/<!-- XML Comment 3 -->/<!--XML Comment 4 -->/g' file.xml
```